# enter array input n solve some question with method

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

i need to know how to do array.
but, we insert the input and no user input.
when complete the table, we must show the average, maximum score, minimum score and identify which the table has maximum or minimum score using the method.. can help me?

Comment: Sounds like homework. If so, you should clearly declare that it is, so that you can get meningful help. You have for example already got an answer suggesting extension methods, but that is not useful if it's a homework question, as the point of the homework is to learn how to use arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Linq offers extension methods:

```
arr.Max()
arr.Min()
arr.Average()
```

Or manually:

```
int maxIndex=0;
int minIndex=0;
double sum=0;
double min=arr[0];
double max=arr[0];

for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
{
  sum+=arr[i];
  if(arr[i]>max)
  {
    max=arr[i];
    maxIndex=i;
  }
  if(arr[i]<min)
  {
    min=arr[i];
    minIndex=i;
  }
}
double average=sum/arr.Length;
```

Note: The behavior in the presence of NaNs might not be as you want.